# Spring boot dockerizing application create files in host machine

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-machine

I have spring boot application and running inside docker.
Now I am creating file in spring boot using

```
File file = new File("/var/www/html");
File f = new File(file, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
```

I want to access this file publically, so have to create in var/www/html folder.

But by doing so, I am unable to see any file inside var/www/html as app is running in docker container.
how can I change Docker container volume so that I can create file in host machine as mentioned above location?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount the volume  when u run you docker image...

If you run your docker image by executing docker run command then add this in command:

docker run .... `-v /var/www/html:/var/www/html` .....

Comment: is this right command?
because for volum tag:
docker run -v <host_path>:<container-path>

Comment: where is wrong? i add ... means your another arguments

Comment: its not working.. shouldn't have to use container path? its both same /var/www/html in the command..

Comment: docker run --restart always --name test -v /var/www/html:/var/www/html -d  -p  82:82 test

Comment: did you give permission to docker user at this location?

Comment: @MihirShah print `file.canRead()` and `file.canWrite()` in you function and check

Comment: Hi, I found that while saving file from my spring boot application, my volume folder inside docker is empty. Then I checked overlay2 folder in docker, and found files are stored in overlay2 folder. how to change it so that file can be saved in volume folder instead of overlay2?